# how to make an input to the calculation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, math

I want to make an input to the method conditions.
First I have a variable "A" I give a default value 0000, the variable "B" I made as an input in the textbox and the variable "N" as the calculation formula, if I enter in the textbox is numeric, directly to the state of "IF B = Length (1 ) "and read the value of variable A" 000 ", then follow the formula" N = A + B ". 
. and finally when I press the button appears on the results of these calculations.,how to structure the program?I possessed the structure shown below

```
Public Class uckondisi

#Region "variabel"
    Private _bilangan As Integer = "0000"
    Private _inputan As Integer = 0
#End Region

#Region "property"
    Public Property bilangan As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._bilangan
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me._bilangan = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property inputan As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._inputan
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me._inputan = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region



    Private Sub btnproses_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnproses.Click

        If Me.txtinputan.Text = 1 Then
            _bilangan = "000"
            Me.txthasil.Text = inputan + bilangan

        Else
end sub
end class
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding what you want, but you seem to be mixing up types. A TextBox can only deal with strings ("this string" or "123" are the same from its point of view). If you want to introduce numbers (and treat them as numbers, for example, for calculations), you would have to perform a conversion to the given type (e.g., Integer): Dim number As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text). The conversion would fail in case of not having a "convertable to number string". You can avoid that either by relying on TryParse of the given numeric type or by checking it via IsNumeric

Comment: ... Two last issues: bear in mind that "000" is different than "0" when treated as a string; but once it is converted into a number, all the trailing zeroes do not matter. If you want to join two strings you can use "&" or "+"; but it is always better to use "&" in order to avoid confusions with the plus sign.... The clarity of your question, the code you wrote, what you have asked, etc. do not belong here (CLOSED worthy). I have answered you because of seeing that all your questions so far have been more or less like this: please, adapt to SO's rules or you will not get any help.

Comment: sorry in advance, problems does I just want to combine two variables, with the condition of "0000" when "000" he had another function to combine with the input,
in this forum I was very new, and I don't understand the requirements of it in this forum. sorry if my post just as spam.

Comment: Don't need to apologise, just do what is expected. Firstly, post a clear question (I cannot even understand your last comment); if you cannot write proper English, just use an online translator; don't post any code, but relevant one for what you want to ask; explain exactly the problems you found, what you tried and why what you tried didn't work; and remember that this is expected to be used by others (= generic questions, with generic problems). Lastly bear in mind that this is a community where you are free to do whatever you want. I have just advised you how to get help easily.

Comment: okay, thank you for your submission, did I use an online translator to interpret what you way,
so I do not understand to speak English with passive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question but there is an obvious problem in your code.

Update with:

```
Private Sub btnproses_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnproses.Click

        If Me.txtinputan.Text = "1" Then
            _bilangan = 000
            Me.txthasil.Text = inputan + bilangan

        End If
End Sub
```

Note the "

Values (i.e. numbers) don't need the "1" however Strings do.

A Textbox shows Text (i.e. a String) which means it needs "1"

If you want a value for it you could use:

```
If Val(txtinputan.Text) = 1 Then
    'Do something
End If
```